# How to parameterize verilog attribute (* *)?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How can I declare a signal with a verilog attribute depending on module's parameter?

I tried:

```
if (KEEP_VERILOG) begin
  (*keep="true"*)reg mysig;
end else begin
  reg mysig;
end

// doing something with mysig
```

I get a synthesis error: `mysig is not declared`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attribute spec allows using constant expressions. Therefore you can use module parameter directly in the attribute:

```
(*keep=KEEP_VERILOG*) reg mysig;
```

The value of the attribute will have the value of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference a signal declared in an unnamed `begin/end` block from outside that block. Give the block a name (and you have to give both blocks the same name for what you want to do) and use that name in the reference.

```
if (KEEP_VERILOG) begin : blockname
    (*keep="true"*)reg mysig;
end else begin : blockname
  reg mysig;
end

// do something with blockname.mysig
```

Comment: It makes sense, this was already in a name block in a generate. I never tried to give the same name for both the if and else. I hope Vivado applies the verilog attribute though. Thanks!

Comment: It actually makes sense but never tried that..